# $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] is not set in PHP post call

Tags: php, post, http-headers

I am trying to access headers (field authorization) from a POST method, but it's never set.

according to

```
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
```

the field "Authorization" is present (sent with postman)

however this evaluates to false

```
$authHeader = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];

if (isset($authHeader))
{
    echo "header field present";
}
else
{
    echo "header field NOT present";
}
```

I am running Apache/PHP/MySql locally on Windows 10
PHP Version is 7.3.7
Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.7

In Postman, I am passing "Content-Type=application/json" and "Authorization=Bearer..."

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually doing it wrong.

If you are passing in "Authorization=Bearer..." than you should read it like:

```
$headers = getallheaders();

print_r($headers["Authorization"]);
```

Comment: Thanks. This actually works. "funfact" that I read nowhere about this variant of doing it. It $Server deprecated or something?

Comment: Noup (not that I know), but this is a custom header you are passing in.

Comment: What exactly is OP doing "wrong"? One would expect `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` to be available, it's somewhat surprising behaviour that it isn't.

Comment: @Roger Note that this solution is very specific to running on Apache, `getallheaders` being an alias for `apache_request_headers`. Just to avoid nasty surprises later on, you'd want to write your code in a way that's not specific to one particular web server. In this case, configuring the web server to pass the `Authorization` header through is the more neutral solution. See the duplicates at the top of your question.

Comment: to provide you with some background info: i've seen this code in a tutorial -> https://www.techiediaries.com/php-jwt-authentication-tutorial/ and also found it in many resources throughout the web. I am using XAMPP. I wan't to use these services from an angular client.